# Is there a word like extracurricular but for work instead of school?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to reference activities that are outside of my profession, and I've been using the word "extracurriculars" to describe them, but it occurs to me that curriculum is academic, not professional. What's the best substitute?

Comment: *Leisure activities*? *Amateur interests*? I suspect the very reason for saying "extracurricular" is to give a veneer of academic legitimacy to what are essentially hobbies, intellectual passions, or forms of civic participation. If they are genuinely interests in adjacent professions or fields, you could coin the phrase "interprofessional interests", but the extra precision in meaning is outweighed by the unfamiliarity of the term.

Comment: 'life' outside work

Comment: You can use *extracurricular* in a figurative sense. Very few people won't be able to make the leap with you.

Comment: [*Extracurricular*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extracurricular) is not confined to academia. It is also used in other areas, such as for work. It's frequently used on resumes.

Comment: I'm with Jason on this, but if you're not comfortable using it this way, try *enrichment activities* or *for enrichment* or *as a hobby*.  Example: I'm going to try a new enrichment activity this semester -- I've been invited to play quartets on Sundays.

Comment: Thanks, Jason et al! Eye-opening feedback. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

avocation  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/avocation)

n.

> An activity taken up in addition to one's regular work or profession,
>   usually for enjoyment; a hobby.

As in:

> I tell people this, and believe this, my vocation and avocation are
>   the same thing. Both are sports broadcasting,” he said. Seattle Times
>   Oct 2018

Comment: I like this one! Not sure why it's getting voted down. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One term in use is **sideline** for which the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sideline) has

> **sideline**
>   NOUN
>   **1** An activity done in addition to one's main job, especially to earn extra income.
>
> *But music was little more than a sideline, and he earned his living in government service.*
>
> *James installed a darkroom in his Silverstream home and took up professional photography as a sideline to his architecture.*

Comment: This term is certainly effective, but I was kind of hoping for something more pompous ;)